# Implicit instantiation of undefined template - Compiler Issue

Tags: c++, macos, templates, clang

I'm trying to compile a program that compiles and runs fine on a Linux system (using both g++ and clang++). 
However, on my Mac, it gives a whole lot of errors similar to the one shown below:
The error comes on "flow".

Some other stackoverflow threads provide answers on providing forward definitions of templates, which I think is already provided on the line having template < typename....

Code Snippet:

```
namespace A {

template <typename T, unsigned NIN, unsigned NOUT, unsigned BUS_WIDTH = 16,
          typename ARB_FN = cm_arb_rr<T, NIN>>
class cm_xbar : public as_module {
  SC_HAS_PROCESS(cm_xbar);

 public:
  std::array<cm_fifo<T, BUS_WIDTH>, NIN> flow;
};
}
```

Error:

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
          'std::__1::array<A::cm_fifo<A::aspkt *, 16, 16>, 1>'
      std::array<cm_fifo<T, BUS_WIDTH>, NIN> flow;
```

Any ideas on why this may be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you compiling with C++11 enabled? Do you `#include <array>`?

Comment: Yes. The makefile has -std=c++11 in it.

Comment: why there is `16, 16`, should it be only `16` for `BUS_WIDTH`?

Comment: `cm_fifo` likely has a third template parameter with a default argument.

Comment: Including <array> didnt make any difference.

Comment: Could the problem be that, instead of std::array, it is the template A:cm_fifo that is not defined above this line?

Comment: Yeah that is not defined above this line. That comes from the SystemC library that has its own files installed elsewhere and included in the header files.

Comment: @masab - and `cm_fifo` is defined in namespace `A`?

Comment: Its defined in the SystemC library, after which another program instantiates it in namespace A (which itself is a huge program that defines the simulator I'm using SystemC for).